# awk not printing variable value

Tags: shell, awk, sed, hive, sh

I am querying a hive tables which gives me multiline output. I want to add a variable value to the beginning of each line of the output. I am running the below command, but the value of the variable is not being substituted:

```
var=case1
`hive -e "select date from table1 limit 5;" | awk -v b=$var 'print b $0'
```

This is giving me the below output:

```
b20180101
b20180202
b20180303
b20180404
b20180505
```

I am expecting the below output:

```
case120180101
case120180202
case120180303
case120180404
case120180505
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What `awk` are you using? BSD `awk`, GNU `awk` and `mawk` all spot the syntax error in you `awk` script. I'm actually really curious to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put your print statement in the awk condition area instead of the action area:

```
awk -v b="$var" '{print b $0}'
```